# Are there Hausdorff spaces which are not locally compact and in which all infinite compact sets have nonempty interior?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Here is the background material from which I am working:

1. The Cantor set is an uncountable compact Hausdorff space with empty
   interior.
2. In a locally compact Hausdorff space, each countable set has empty interior.
3. The rational numbers with the subspace topology is a non-locally compact Hausdorff space in which all compact sets have empty interior.

I am trying to find a non-locally compact Hausdorff space in which all infinite compact sets have nonempty interior. I am guessing the example will be an exotic function space.

Comment: Your point 2 doesn't hold, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space with the discrete topology.

Comment: But in a locally compact Hausdorff space each countable union of nowhere dense sets has empty interior, i.e. it is a Baire space. So if a point is nowhere dense, which means it is not open, then 2) is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ with the discrete topology on $\Bbb R$, and a neighborhood of $\infty$ is a set with a countable complement. This $X$ is clearly Hausdorff.
Now, the funny thing about this space is that each compact set is finite. Such a space is called *anti-compact*. To see this, let $S$ be an infinite subset. If it avoids $\infty$, then it has the discrete topology and is not compact. If $\infty\in S$, then choose a countable subset $Q$ of $S$ and note that $(S-Q)\cup\bigcup_{q\in Q}\{q\}$ is an infinite open cover of $S$ without a finite subcover. This means that no infinite set is compact. In particular, $\infty$ has no compact neighborhood, so $X$ is not locally compact.

Now, the property you wish for is vacuously satisfied since there are no infinite compact subsets :-)

Comment: I was *this close* to figuring out something similar. Argh! Now of course the question needs to change to eliminate such....

Comment: Well, you could try to find a space where there **do** exist infinite compact subsets :)

Comment: Thank you, Stefan, for this creative solution. I am not sure of the protocol on this site - is it OK for me to change my poorly posed question to "Is there a Hausdorff space which: (1) is not locally compact, (2) contains at least one infinite compact subset, and (3) all infinite compact sets have nonempty interior?" If so, do I edit the original posting or inline in the comments?

Comment: @Wayne: I suggest you ask a new question since it is actually a different question with a more difficult solution. You should mention this question in the new post and point out the differences, so the readers won't accidentally mark it as a duplicate.