# Is there a non-locally compact Hausdorff space in which all infinite compact sets (of which there is at least one) have uncountable interiors?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

Here is the background material from which I am working:

- The Cantor set is an uncountable compact Hausdorff subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ with empty interior.
- In a locally compact Hausdorff space with no isolated points, each countable set has empty interior.
- The rational numbers with the subspace topology is a non-locally compact Hausdorff space in which all compact sets have empty interior.

I am trying to find a non-locally compact Hausdorff space in which there are infinite compact sets, and where all of the infinite compact sets have uncountable interiors. I am guessing the example will be an exotic function space.

I first posed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441656/are-there-hausdorff-spaces-which-are-not-locally-compact-and-in-which-all-infini) without specifying that there should be at least one infinite compact set, and this was solved by Stefan H. on this site. I then posed [this updated question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444610/is-there-a-non-locally-compact-hausdorff-space-in-which-all-infinite-compact-set), which was solved by Dejan Govc.

Comment: "In a locally compact Hausdorff space, each countable set has empty interior." That's not true (consider $\mathbb{Z}$), you need to require that it has no isolated points.

Comment: Please write the exact, and complete question *in the question body* rather than in its title.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{Q}\times \{0\} \cup \mathbb{R}\times \{1\}$? It's not locally compact, and for $a < b \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $[a,\,b]\times\{1\}$ is compact and has interior $(a,\,b)\times\{1\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I think he meant that there are infinite compact sets, and all of them have uncountable interior, and not "there are infinite compact sets with uncountable interior".

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, I meant the question as Stefan indicates. I also took Asaf's advice and rewrote the question in the question body, with some wordsmithing to clarify.

Comment: @Wayne Okay, I just wanted to determine the requirements. So there should be infinite compact subsets, and every infinite compact subset should have uncountable interior. Is one infinite compact subset enough, or should there be infinitely many?

Comment: Note that a very common set among the countable compact subsets is a convergent sequence together with its limit. If this sequence has infinitely many values, then it is an infinite compact subset, but clearly it can only have a countable interior. So it must consist of finitely many values, and for a convergent sequence in a Hausdorff space this means that it is eventually equal to its limit. So all convergent sequences are eventually constant.

Comment: If $K$ is an infinite compact subset, then $\overset{\circ}{K}$ is a locally compact (open) subspace. Since any infinite compact subset shall have nonempty interior, no point in $\overset{\circ}{K}$ can have a countable base of neighbourhoods. And every sequence (that contains infinitely many distinct points) in $\overset{\circ}{K}$ must have uncountably many cluster points.

Comment: Now let $V \subset\mspace{-2mu}\subset \overset{\circ}{K}$ an open neighbourhood of $x$. Since $\partial V$ is compact and has no interior points, it is finite. Looks odd, but I don't see a contradiction yet.

Comment: Your statement, “The Cantor set is an uncountable compact Hausdorff space with empty interior” is not really right. One speaks of the interior of a *subset* of a topological space, so it’s true that the interior of Cantor as a subset of $\mathbb R$ is empty. But the interior of Cantor as a subset of itself is (of course) the whole space. Just as the interior of $\mathbb R$ is the whole real line; but as a subset of the plane, its interior is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following.

At last you obtain a positive answer, because of the following

*Lemma.* Each infinite locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ contains an infinite closed subspace with a countable interior.

So if you have an infinite compact subspace $X$ of a Hausdorff space $Z$ then  $X$ contains an infinite closed subspace with a countable interior not only in $Z$, but even in $X$.

*Proof of Lemma*. Suppose the converse. Let $Y=\{y_n:n\in\omega\}$ be an arbitrary countable infinite subset of $X$. Then the set $\overline Y$ is uncountable. Let $x\in \overline Y\backslash Y$ be an arbitrary point. Since the space $X$ is Hausdorff, for each number $n\in\omega$ there exist disjoint open neighborhoods $U_n$ and $V_n$ of the points $y_n$ and $x$ respectively. The set $\overline Y\backslash\bigcup U_n $ is a closed set with an empty interior and therefore it is finite. Then the set $\overline Y\cap \bigcap V_n\subset \overline Y\backslash\bigcup U_n$ is finite too. Thus the point $x$ has a countable pseudocharacter $\psi(x,\overline{Y})$ in the space $\overline {Y}$. Since the space $X$ is locally compact, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of the point $x$ such that the set $\overline V$ is compact. Then $\psi(x,\overline{Y\cap V})\le \psi(x,\overline{Y})\le\omega$. Since the space $\overline {V\cap Y}$ is compact, the character $\chi(x,\overline {V\cap Y})$ is countable too. Since the set $Y$ is dense in the space $\overline{V\cap Y}$ and $x\not\in Y$, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of distinct points of the set $Y$  converging to $x$. Then the set $\{x_n\}\cup\{x\}$ is a countable infinite compact set, and hence an infinite closed subset of the space $X$ with countable interior, a contradiction.$\square$

**Update**. Moreover, we can improve Lemma to

*Lemma 2.* Each infinite Hausdorff space $X$ contains an infinite closed subspace with a countable interior.

*Proof*. Suppose the converse. Let $Y=\{y_n:n\in\omega\}$ be an arbitrary countable infinite subset of $X$. Then the set $\overline Y\backslash Y$ is uncountable. For each $n\in\omega$ we define by induction an open neighborhood $U_n$ of the point $y_n$ such that a set $Z_n=\overline Y\backslash (Y\cup\bigcup_{i\le n} U_i)$ is infinite and a point $z_n\in Z_n$ such that all the points $z_i$ are distinct and $z_i\not\in U_n$ for each $i<n$. If for each neighborhood $U$ of the point $y_0$ the set $\overline Y\backslash (Y\cup U)$ is finite, then for any countable infinite subset $Z$ of the set $\overline Y\backslash Y$ the set $Z\cup \{y_0\}$ is a countable compact set, a contradiction. Therefore we can choose an open neighborhood $U_0$ of the point $y_0$ such that the set $Z_0=\overline Y\backslash (Y\cup U)$ is infinite and a point $z_0\in Z_0$. If for each neighborhood $U$ of the point $y_1$ the set $Z_0\backslash U$ is finite, then for any countable infinite subset $Z$ of the set $Z_0$ the set $Z\cup \{y_1\}$ is a countable compact set, a contradiction. Therefore we can choose an open neighborhood $U_1\not\ni z_0$ of the point $y_1$ such that the set $Z_1=Z_0\backslash U_1$ is infinite and a point $z_1$ in $Z_1\backslash\{z_0\}$, and so forth. Then $\overline{\{z_n:n\in\omega\}}\subset\overline{Y}\backslash\bigcup U_n$ is a nowhere dense closed infinite subset of the space $\overline Y$, a contradiction.$\square$

**Update 2.** Moreover, we can prove

*Proposition.* Each infinite Hausdorff space $X$ containing infinitely many non-isolated points contains also an infinite closed subset with empty interior.

*Proof*. Suppose the converse. Denote  the set of all non-isolated points of $X$ as $X’$. Let $Y=\{y_n:n\in\omega\}\subset X’$ be an arbitrary countable infinite subset. It is clear that $\overline Y\subset X’$.

We shall need the following

*Lemma 3*. There are no infinite subset $Z$ of the set $X’$ and a point $x\in X$ such that for each neighborhood $U$ of the point $x$ the set $Z\backslash U$ is finite.

*Proof*. Suppose the converse. Then the set $Z_0=Z\cup \{x\}$ is a compact set. Moreover, let 
$y\in Z_0\backslash \{x\}$ be an arbitrary point. There exist disjoint open sets $U\ni x$ and $V\ni y$. Hence $V\cap Z_0$ is a finite neighborhood of the point $y$. Therefore, the space $Z_0\backslash \{x\}$ is discrete. The set $Z_0$ is closed in $X$ as its compact subset. Since the set $Z_0$ is infinite, there exists a non-empty open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $V\subset Z_0$. Since the set $Z_0\backslash \{x\}$ is dense in $Z_0$, there exists a point $y\in V\cap (Z_0\backslash \{x\})$. Since the space $Z_0\backslash \{x\}$ is discrete, there exists a neighborhood $W$ of the point $y$ such that $W\cap (Z_0\backslash \{x\})$ is a singleton. But then a set $W\cap V\subset W\cap (Z_0\backslash \{x\})$ is a singleton too, a contradiction, because all points from the set $Z_0\backslash \{x\}\subset X’$ are non-isolated. $\square$

Now we shall consider two cases.

$1.$ The set $\overline Y\backslash Y$ is infinite. For each $n\in\omega$ we define by induction an open neighborhood $U_n$ of the point $y_n$ such that a set $Z_n=\overline Y\backslash (Y\cup\bigcup_{i\le n} U_i)$ is infinite and a point $z_n\in Z_n$ such that all the points $z_i$ are distinct and $z_i\not\in U_n$ for each $i<n$. By Lemma 3, there exists an open neighborhood $U_0$ of the point $y_0$ such that the set $ Z_0=\overline Y\backslash (Y\cup U)$ is infinite. Choose an arbitrary point $z_0\in Z_0$. Again by Lemma 3, there exists an open neighborhood $U_1\not\ni z_0$ of the point $y_1$ such that the set $Z_1=Z_0\backslash U_1$ is infinite. Choose an arbitrary point $z_1\in Z_1\backslash\{z_0\}$, and so forth. Then $\overline{\{z_n:n\in\omega\}}\subset\overline{Y}\backslash\bigcup U_n$ is a nowhere dense closed infinite subset of the space $\overline Y$, a contradiction.

$2.$ The set $\overline Y\backslash Y$ is finite. Since $\overline Y\subset X’$, without loss of generality, we can assume that 
$\overline Y=Y$. For each $n\in\omega$ we define by induction an open neighborhood $U_n$ of the point $y_n$ such that a set $Z_n=Y\backslash \bigcup_{i\le n} U_i$ is infinite and a point $z_n\in Z_n$ such that all the points $z_i$ are distinct. By Lemma 3, there exists an open neighborhood $U_0$ of the point $y_0$ such that the set $Z_0=Y\backslash U_0$ is infinite. Choose an arbitrary point $z_0\in Z_0$. Again by Lemma 3, there exists an open neighborhood $U_1$ of the point $y_1$ such that the set $Z_1=Z_0\backslash U_1$ is infinite. Choose an arbitrary point $z_0\in Z_1\backslash\{z_0\}$, and so forth. Put $Z=\{z_i:i\in\omega\}$. Then $\overline Z\subset\overline Y=Y$. Let $y\in Y$. Then $y=y_n$ for some $n\in\omega$. Then the intersection $U_n\cap Z\subset U_n\cap (Z\backslash Z_n)$ is a finite set. Therefore $Z$ is a discrete (in particular, a closed) subset of the space $X$. Suppose that the set $Z$ has non-empty interior. Then there exists a non-empty open set $U$ such that $U\subset Z$. Then there exists 
a number $n$ such that $U_n\cap U$ is a nonempty open set. But $U_n\cap U\subset U_n\cap Z$ is a singleton, a contradiction, because all points from the set $Z$ are non-isolated. $\square$

Comment: I did not read your proofs, but in $\mathbb R$ there are no countable open sets (except $\emptyset$).

Comment: "Then the set $\overline{Y}$ is uncountable." There is a priori no reason to believe it has nonempty interior.

Comment: @DanielFischer If $\overline Y$ has empty interior then it is the required subset.

Comment: Ah, I begin to pierce through your formulations. Could be I'm too tired, or perhaps they aren't as clear as they could.

Comment: @DanielFischer Maybe you are right. As you can see from the growth of my answer, now I am going through a development phase of the investigation and trying to obtain new results. It seems for me that the conditions, which are imposed on the spaces, are extremely strong, so I tried to deal with and to “concretise” such  spaces.  If you have any ideas or remarks, how to improve or simplify the results, feel free to comment.

Comment: @Wayne As you can see above, your question suggested a bunch of new results. I do not know 
are they worthy to be published and I’ll ask my scientific consultant, Professor [Taras Banakh](http://www.franko.lviv.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/index.html) about this. In the positive case, we can write a small joint article devoted to the subject.

Comment: @Wayne I have a talk with my scientific consultant. He wrote that these questions are too simple for publication, so I suggest a publication provided we can advance the results or solve a problem.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I encourage you to publish any results stemming from this question. I do not hold any intellectual property here. I am just asking some questions. Thank you for your insight. I still have to digest your latest result.

Comment: @AlexRavsky It makes me wonder what conditions on a Hausdorff space ensure there exists an infinite convergent sequence.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Maybe a structure theorem for Hausdorff spaces could be formulated - the set of non-isolated points $X'$ and its complement. An equivalence relation could be defined: two convergent sequences are equivalent if, after all terms from the "isolated component" are discarded, the sequences are equal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9689/discussion-between-alex-ravsky-and-wayne)

Comment: @AlexRavsky Sorry - I have trouble logging into the chat site. Your proposition answers my question, "Is there a non-locally compact Hausdorff space in which all infinite compact sets (of which there is at least one) have uncountable interiors?", provided that the space has infinitely many non-isolated points.